Why does this error(Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component) occur here?
Reference:
This code: electron-trpc demo
I have created a corresponding demo: electron-10-demo-etrpc.
However, when running it, an error occurs:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM).
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

The error is reported in the file src/renderer/src/HelloElectron.tsx at this line:
const res = trpcReact.greeting.useQuery({ name: 'Electron' }); // when execute this line it report error

This line of code is not written outside of a functional component. So why does this error occur here?

Hooks must be called out the top level of your component (see point 2 in the error message). It's erroring because you're breaking the rules of hooks.

As you know, a React component is rendered or invoked initially upon starting the App, this is called the initial render. Subsequent to this, it will render again for all changes in its states. In all these cases, the process remains the same - the component is rendering. It is essentially invoking the functional object. As a result, it will return JSX. The JSX may include event handlers. Event handlers will run when the UI will undergo interactions.
We discussed this much to get the basis to say that there are two distinct types of codes running here. The codes with runs on render, and the codes which run as event handlers.
All hooks, including custom hooks, must run as part of component render. It cannot be run as part of event handlers.
Now coming to your code, HelloElectron is the functional object invoked as when the component is rendered. And it returns the following JSX. The JSX has an event handler clickHandle.
 return (
    <>
      <div data-testid="greeting">{data ? data!.text : ''}</div>
      <button onClick={clickHandle}>click me</button>
    </>
  )

This event handler clickHandle mentioned above, has the following code. The second statement within it is an invocation of a hook. However, as we discussed above, it is not possible to invoke a hook from an event handler. This invocation must be included in the rendering. This is the issue at present the code would have.
 const clickHandle = () => {

    console.log('clicked')
    const res = trpcReact.greeting.useQuery({ name: 'Electron' });  // when execute this line it report error

    if(res && res.data) { data = res.data }

    console.log('props: ', props)

  }

Obviously, if you need to invoke a hook in response to a user interaction like button click, you may need to do the following steps.
// 1. Move the invocation of the hook from the event to the component body.
// 2. Then you may trigger a render.
// 3. In order to trigger a render, there must be at least one state would change.

